# Is there a way to figure out a visitor's prior URL before landing on my page?

Tags: javascript

Here's the situation:

I am working with a site that forwards users from (SITE A), to a mobile version (SITE B), like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
if($(window).width() < 480){
window.location = "http://mysite.com/mobile-version"
}
});
</script>
```

Problem is, we still need to offer users the option to return to (SITE A) from within (SITE B), but with that script in place it's just going to run the script again when users request (SITE A) and return to (SITE B).

Can an IF/ELSE statement pull the user's last visited page/site and say well...you're visiting (SITE A) from (SITE B), so no need for the re-direct?

Comment: creating a session for the user on server side would be the easiest way to do this

Comment: window.location = document.referrer;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The DOM property you're looking for is [document.referrer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.referrer).

It returns a string containing the page the user was on before they came to this page. i.e.

```
var prevPage = document.referrer;
if (!prevPage.match(/*SITE A*/)){
//Do Something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A server side session would best for complete cross-browser support but if you want to do it on the client side you can use HTML 5 LocalStorage if both the mobile and desktop site are on the same domain.

On the mobile site, when the user clicks to show the desktop site, store a value in localStorage:

```
// user wants to go to desktop site
localStorage.setItem("no-mobile-redirect", true);
window.location = 'http://desktopsite';
```

On the desktop site:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if($(window).width() < 480){
        var localVar = localStorage.getItem("no-mobile-redirect");

        if(!localVar){ // only redirect if the no-mobile-redirect is not TRUE
            window.location = "http://mysite.com/mobile-version"
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for submitting this response. I was not aware of, but definitely going to look into LocalStorage.

Answer (score 1):

Racheet's answer is correct, as far as it goes, however it's not safe to rely on this. Some web browsers can be configured to not send a REFERER header for privacy reasons, and some firewalls/routers will do this too.

Your best bet is to instead only perform the redirect if a querystring (or form) parameter is not present. For example:

- "http://mysite.a.com/" - will redirect to Site B
- "http://mysite-b.com/" - user is now at the mobile site, but clicks a 'view full site link'...
- "http://mysite-a.com/?noredirect=true" - you note the parameter and do not redirect.

Other alternatives could perhaps involve using cookies or localstorage, but again you need to consider the possibility that the user's client doesn't support those features or has them turned off.

Answer (score 0):

Just offering another solution.
Use a parameter in the URL when redirecting to desktop: http://mysite.com?rd=false

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  if (window.location.indexOf("rd=false" != -1) return;
  if($(window).width() < 480){
    window.location = "http://mysite.com/mobile-version"
  }
});
```

Come to think about it: a cookie would be more practical...